# Tutorial for raster analyse in ArcGIS or QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, raster, analysis, tools

Does anybody know where I can find some good tutorial for raster analyse in ArcGIS or QGIS?

Comment: Where did you look prior to posting your question?  I think that a number should be easily discoverable via a Google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some tutorials:

**ArcGIS**

- http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/pdf/spatial-analyst-tutorial.pdf
- http://www.colgate.edu/portaldata/imagegallerywww/9f6bbcda-184d-4f20-bf0f-05069a418363/ImageGallery/15_GEOG245_Tutorial8.pdf

**QGIS**

- http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/10/tutorial-basic-raster-analysis-and.html
- http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/interpolating_point_data.html
- http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-working-with-rasters-in-qgis.html

Comment: Do you have a link where I can find the data for this first tutorial?

Comment: @Slobodan See page 3 of the pdf:  `The data required is included on the ArcGIS Desktop CD. After running the ArcGIS setup, on the Additional
Installation Components dialog box, check to install the ArcGIS Tutorial Data. On the ArcGIS Tutorial
Data Setup wizard, check to install the Spatial Analyst data (the default installation path is
C:\arcgis\ArcTutor\SpatialAnalyst). `

Comment: You may want to help improve the Community Wiki on half of this question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5301/seeking-reference-tutorial-for-arcgis-spatial-analyst